# How to build Distiller class for BERT and variants using TF models from HF

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to build a "Distillation" class for Knowledge Distillation using TF models from Hugging Face. I started with [this](https://colab.research.google.com/github/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/vision/ipynb/knowledge_distillation.ipynb) and tried to modify it.

I built a dataset that looks like this:

```
DatasetDict({
train: Dataset({
    features: ['text', 'labels', 'input_ids', 'token_type_ids', 'attention_mask'],
    num_rows: 512
})
validation: Dataset({
    features: ['text', 'labels', 'input_ids', 'token_type_ids', 'attention_mask'],
    num_rows: 128
})
test: Dataset({
    features: ['text', 'labels', 'input_ids', 'token_type_ids', 'attention_mask'],
    num_rows: 160
})})
```

and calling features on the "train" I receive:

```
{'labels': ClassLabel(num_classes=4, names=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], id=None), 'text': Value(dtype='string', id=None)}
```

from which I created train (but also valid and test) as follows:

```
tf_train_dataset = my_tokenized_dataset["train"].to_tf_dataset(
columns=["attention_mask", "input_ids", "token_type_ids"],
label_cols=["labels"],
shuffle=True,
collate_fn=data_collator,
batch_size=8,)
```

Supposing this correct (I followed [HF tutorials](https://huggingface.co/course/chapter3/2?fw=tf)), I called

```
teacher = TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(checkpoint, num_labels=4) 
student = TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(checkpoint, num_labels=4) 
loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True) 
teacher.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=loss, metrics=["accuracy"]) # where opt is Adam with a lr_scheduler
```

and fitted the teacher model in 3 epochs with about 95% validation accuracy.

Leaving unchanged the Distill class from the TF tutorial, the problem arise when it is needed to calculate the student_loss: in detail, I checked that

```
x = {'input_ids': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(None, None) dtype=int64>, 'token_type_ids': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:2' shape=(None, None) dtype=int64>, 'attention_mask': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, None) dtype=int64>}
```

and

```
y = Tensor("IteratorGetNext:3", shape=(None,), dtype=int64)
```

while

```
Teacher predictions: TFSequenceClassifierOutput(loss=None, logits=<tf.Tensor 'tf_bert_for_sequence_classification_1/classifier/BiasAdd:0' shape=(None, 4) dtype=float32>, hidden_states=None, attentions=None)
Student predictions: TFSequenceClassifierOutput(loss=None, logits=<tf.Tensor 'tf_bert_for_sequence_classification_2/classifier/BiasAdd:0' shape=(None, 4) dtype=float32>, hidden_states=None, attentions=None)
```

The error is the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback         (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-a15be00a8e5e> in <module>()
11 
12 # Distill teacher to student
---> 13 distiller.fit(tf_train_dataset, validation_data=tf_validation_dataset, epochs=3)
14 
15 # Evaluate student on test dataset

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-   packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py in     error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
68     finally:
69       del filtered_tb

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
1145           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
1146             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
-> 1147               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
1148             else:
1149               raise

TypeError: in user code:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1010, in step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1000, in run_step  **
    outputs = model.train_step(data)
File "<ipython-input-61-219884772d38>", line 52, in train_step
    student_loss = self.student_loss_fn(y, student_predictions)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 141, in __call__
    losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 245, in call  **
    return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 1860, in sparse_categorical_crossentropy
    y_pred = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_pred)

TypeError: Expected any non-tensor type, but got a tensor instead.
```

I apologize if the questions and mistakes are trivial, I still have a lot to learn unfortunately. Better yet, if you can give me a step-by-step answer without taking anything for granted maybe it will be easier for me to understand.

Thanks in advance to everyone.